# Implementing bridge network of substrate and getting error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` required by bp_runtime

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I have already synced sp-io in all of the cargo.toml to same file and also tried cargo clean and deleting cargo.lock but still getting the same error. Can someone please help me.

[This is the screenshot containing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm1kJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are leaking the standard library twice somewhere in a dependency. This usually translates to: for some pallet `x`, where pallet `x` has feature `std`, you have forgotten to add `x/std` somewhere.

Recall that all FRAME crates need to be imported with `default-features = false`, and their `std` feature enabled in the top crate's `std`.

Comment: All crates are imported with default-features = false, except the ones in dev-dependencies and also i didn't get what you mean by "their std feature enabled in the top crate's std"